# JPGs seem corrupted on Arch but are good on Fedora and Windows7

Tags: arch-linux, jpeg, multimedia

I re-installed Arch on my computer (clean install). Since then when copying images (JPG) and movies (mov) from SD card they seem to be corrupted. 
When rsync-ing to the computer some of the files presents error messages, and when trying to open using Shotwell i get gray square. Movie files opened in VLC are making annoying noises and the screen is black.
I tried opening the same SD card with the same files on other systems, and nothing is wrong with the files.

Any ideas?

Update:
In dmesg i get tons of:

```
DMA: Out of SW-IOMMU space for 65536 bytes at device 0000:00:1d.0
```

Update #2:
I ran VLC from CLI and received the following message:

```
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_i965.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked around and it seems to be related to the latest kernel:

```
4.0.1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 29 12:00:26 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'll be grateful for any ideas regarding this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding endianness - see my answer: What kinds of hardware are you running (which processors)? Admittedly, it's a rather wild guess...

Comment: If not, get us more details:  
What is the rsync command with options?  
Do the files keep the size?
Can you save "1234567890" to a file, transfer it, an d post both variants?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it's not an rsync issue. I have the same problem even when opening the files directly from the SD card.

Comment: Ok, the other questions still stand, they are not related to rsync. Curious

Comment: Oh, I se I confused some parts of the setup - could you describe the simpelest test you can make, with no rsync, and what exactly you do with the car?

Comment: If you copy a corrupt file on arch, do you get a corrupt copy on arch , and have tow working copies later? (Anywat, first transfer a file with "1234567890" text and look at it.)

Comment: Can you copy the files from SD card to a USB stick and see if they are viewable on another computer, that would rule out any kind of hardware corruption/problem reading the files.  Do you have the correct graphics drivers installed and is the system fully up to date?

Comment: Thanks. I'll do everything later today and report back. As for the system - it's a newly installed Arch 64bit that was updated yesterday. I use Intel graphics i915, but i'm pretty sure it's not a graphic card issue. Some photos and movies that were created using the same camera and were copied a week ago works well (it was hard copying the movie files as well, but after a restart they work).

Comment: Well - it is getting even more annoying: now it's able to display the JPGs and the MOVs on the Arch machine as well. I don't really know why it's so random.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an endian diference issue, somehow... which is normally worked around automatically.

Is that possible? if you have computers that have a different byte order, the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness),
the data needs to be converted, switching every two byte.
That is normally done by the internet protocols. But you could go around that, like when you use SD cards.

How can the card know in which kind of computer is is? It will be the same in both.

But one of the computers may use the data assuming they are correctly converted for local use, and get it mixed up - while it's still correct seen from the other side, and continues to work there.

Note it woud need some additional complication, as I thing the data on SD cards may be stored in a standard order, so it's converted.

Comment: This is not an answer.  You should have added it as a comment to the original post.

Comment: @Bill Yes, you're right. My idea was to see it as answer if the endian thing woud be the problem, (Then, I added additional comments, hiding that there was at least something like a answer). Ok, I move the comments now, and I'm happy to delete the answer it the guess was too far off to be useful  - let's have tho OP have a look.